# Access denied file in asp.net core

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

When i publish my project to `iis` and i do upload a picture on browser so this operation is fails and show this error in `logger sysytem`

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\qarbal.com\back.qarbal.com\wwwroot\images\UserProfile\pic_50.jpg' is denied.System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\qarbal.com\back.qarbal.com\wwwroot\images\UserProfile\pic_50.jpg' is denied.
>      at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)

ActionController

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPhoto()
{
    var uploadsRootFolder = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "images\\UserProfile");
    var files = Request.Form.Files;     
    foreach (var file in files)
    {       
        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsRootFolder, queryModel.Name  + files[0].FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    return Json("ok");  
}
```

`startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

How to solve this Exception ?

Comment: It looks like your app pool doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Most likely the app pool identity doesn't have access to that path. Try giving it access to `c:\inetpub` (and all of its sub-directories). If the app pool runs as an impersonated user, you should pick a different folder than `inetpub`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right click on the `wwwroot` folder -> Properties -> Security tab -> Click at `Edit` button -> Enter `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` user -> Click at `Check names` -> OK -> Then give it `Write permission`.

Comment: not working, those this changes need to restart the server or?

Comment: This worked for me except the user name was called `IIS IUSRS`, which I found listed under the Advanced button in the Add user menu.

Comment: Isnt it risky to give eveyrthing write permission?

Comment: It's not everything. It's only the user of your app's pool in the IIS. The rest of it should be controlled by your app.

Answer (score -2):

Work fine...

```
string fileName = file_name+".pdf";

           string files = System.IO.Path.Combine("pdf/") + fileName;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(files))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", new { message = "File Not Found" });

            }
            else
            {

                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(files);
                return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, files);

            }
```