# Aspnet core where to find default app pool name of a project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, application-pool, static-files

While I am attempting to save static files in the wwwroot, my aspnet core app throws:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path <path> denied.
```

I have already found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935373/8475133, but I cannot get the right application pool name: DefaultAppPool and IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool does not work. Where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open IIS Manager, select your website in left hand pane, and then click `Basic Settings` in the right hand pane. It will display a modal dialog and from here you can find the Application pool used by your application Pool
[image]

Next, select the Application Pools in left pane, and the then click `Advanced Settings` in right pane. It will show the Application Pool properties. `Identity` property is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`

**Note:** Since you are deploying ASP.NET Core application ensure your `.NET CLR Version` property is set to `No Managed Code`

[image]

Next for setting the write permissions for Application Pool User, select your website in left pane, right click and then click `Edit Permissions`. In the opened dialog box, go to the Security tab and then click `Edit`. Click `Add` and then type in the Application Pool Identity user. The format for Application Pool user is **IIS AppPool{Application pool name}** for example for DefaultAppPool the username will be `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`. Next click on `Check Names` button and in case of valid name the username will be underlined in the TextArea. Finally click `OK`.

[image]

Next with the IIS App Pool user selected, check the `Modify` checkbox and click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Application pool by going to **`Application Pool -> Add Application Pool`**
as follows,

[image]

Comment: Where to find this dialog and where to set this new application pool for debugging in visual studio 2017.

Comment: you can find this in the IIS

Comment: were you able to sort it out